# Vim NERDTree: navigate to directory bookmark without changing tree root

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there any way to use a *directory* bookmark in Vim's [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) plugin without changing the NERDTree root to the bookmark directory?

When I use directory bookmarks, I find myself typing <kbd>C</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in the NERDTree window afterwards to get the root back to my CWD. I'd prefer that NERDTree instead expand the tree view and highlight the bookmark directory. I poked at the source code briefly and didn't see any way to change this behavior, but I'm hoping I missed something.

I'd like similar behavior for any bookmark (files or directories), but mostly for directories.

Comment: Why don't you simply [send a feature request](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues) to the author?